# VirtualHost prevents XAMPP from stating start Apache

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I just install the lastest XAMPP on Windows 10.
Not changing any configuration, Apache starts.
Now I need to configure multiple local sites.
Sites duely point to 127.0.0.1 in windows hosts file.

Now I try to configura a first site in Apache.

"httpd.conf" is untouched.
Optionally I tried adding `Listen 8080` to it.

in httpd-vhosts.conf, I have

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin admin@whatever-domain
    DocumentRoot "path-to-my-project\www"
    ServerName mydomainname.local
    ServerAlias www.mydomainname.local
    ErrorLog "path-to-my-project\xampp-logs\error.log"
    CustomLog "path-to-my-project\xampp-logs\custom.log"
    <Directory "path-to-my-project\www"></Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Alternatively, I tried with port 80

XAMPP Control Panel says:

> 18:51:31  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. 18:51:31 
>   [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
>   18:51:31  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by
>   another method. 18:51:31  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view
>   error logs and check 18:51:31  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for
>   more clues 18:51:31  [Apache]     If you need more help, copy and post
>   this 18:51:31  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums

Logs are empty.

I tried launching XAMPP Control Panel with Administrator rights. . And installed Apache and MySql services from there ... not sure those were required.   `[Apache]     Clicking on start on Apache line now asks me for administrator permission, and then stays stuck on 18:53:50 Attempting to start Apache service...`

I tried correct the Skype settings that used to block port 80 but didn't find the match in current version of Skype. I assume it was for older versions. Yet, I assume it would have prevented Apache from starting even just after installation, not after I tried configuration virtual host.

I have not uninstall "Apache" and "MySQL" services from XAMPP Control Panel, since I suspect they are not what I'm trying to start. Starting deosn't get stuck and exists with the error message again.

Event viewers contains some entries, but they seem to be related to specific trys and do not repeat when I try to start Apache again.
I'm not sure if they are relevant, but here are some:

> CustomLog takes two or three arguments, a file name, a custom log format string or format name, and an optional "env=" or "expr=" clause
>   (see docs)     .
>
> AH00526: Syntax error on line 52 of .../httpd-vhosts.conf:     .
>
> AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next
>   release .../httpd-vhosts.conf:45
>
> > httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 521 of .../httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 54 of .../httpd-vhosts.conf: Expected  but saw      .
> >     (Hm, that's not what I see in my file ...)

Answer (score 0):

I commented the CustumLog line. Apache is now starting.